# Creating optimal query of oracle db using EF

Tags: entity-framework, oracle10g

I have an Oracle database where I am storing information about customers.
One of the fields is user number.

My `UserNumber` column is type of text.

A user sends a number in various formats:

- +44777XXXXXXX
- 777XXXXXXX
- 0777XXXXXXX

So far I have:

```
var list = context.UserDetails.Where(x => x.UserNumber == number).ToList();
```

I can also do this with:

```
var strippedNumber = ConvertNumberToBasic(number); // this will return me number as 777XXXXXXX

now 

var list = context.UserDetails.Where(x => x.UserNumber.Contains(number)).ToList();
```

Is there a more optimal way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to ask the customer what they need before you can write any code for this...